# How to customize the appearance of table view multiple selection?

Tags: ios, tableview

Say I have a regular table view with some cells in it:

[image]

I would like the table view to respond to an external action to make it go to a "selecting" mode. If the action fires, all the cells need to be translated to the right side, revealing the indicators, so that I can tap on a cell to "select" it (fill the indicator) or "deselect" it (unfill the indicator), as shown below:

[image]

It seems the `selected` or `highlighted` state of `UITableViewCell` does not ring a bell for this effect. I also tried setting the transform in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `willDisplayCell`, but they did not work.

Comment: why don't you try allows multiple selection?

Comment: @johnykumar Multiple selection is OK with me, my problem is how to achieve this effect that all cells slide to the right, revealing the indicators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have the self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem; added to viewDidLoad and self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES; set? it automatically moves cells to the right, or at least the labels.

Here is a good working example for customization -

[Apple Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/tablemultiselect/Listings/MultiSelectTableView_APLMasterViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011189-MultiSelectTableView_APLMasterViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6)

Comment: This sample code is exactly what I need, cheers! Maybe I should change the question title to "How to customize the appearance of table view editing mode?"